# Running a SQL script not returning that is now not retuning all the rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am running a script that I have used over the last few months and all of a sudden it starts not to return all the users listed, basically had over 4500 users in the system and now its only returning between 1000 to 1500. Which is odd as the script hasent changed and the users are all still there. Also when I refresh the script the number of rows returned changes some times it goes up and some time it goes down. Another strange thing is it use to return all the rows at once now its only doing it 50 at a time?

Any help would be apprecated.

Here is the script

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT INITTEAM(ounit.name) "Team",
          tuser.name "User Name",
          tuser.created_date "User Created Date" ,
          extract(YEAR FROM
                   (SELECT max(logon_date)
                    FROM fife_logon_history
                    WHERE user_name = tuser.name)) "Year Last Logged In" ,
          extract(MONTH FROM
                   (SELECT max(logon_date)
                    FROM fife_logon_history
                    WHERE user_name = tuser.name)) "Month Last Logged In" ,
          initname(person.first_names) || ' ' || initname(person.family_name) "Worker Name" ,
          bemplo.employment_end_date "Employ. End Date" ,
          dba_users.account_status "Account Status" ,
          (SELECT listagg(tugrou.description,/*chr(10)*/',') 
                    within GROUP (ORDER BY tugmem.tuser_identifier,
                                           tugrou.description)
      FROM tugmem
      JOIN tugrou ON tugrou.identifier = tugmem.tugrou_identifier
      WHERE tugmem.tuser_identifier = tuser.identifier
      GROUP BY tugmem.tuser_identifier) "Access Permissions" ,
          CASE WHEN (SELECT listagg(tugrou.description, chr(10)) 
                               within GROUP (ORDER BY tugmem.tuser_identifier,
                                                      tugrou.description)
                      FROM tugmem
                      JOIN tugrou ON tugrou.identifier = tugmem.tugrou_identifier
                      WHERE tugmem.tuser_identifier = tuser.identifier
                      GROUP BY tugmem.tuser_identifier) LIKE '%AIS %' THEN 'AIS User '
               WHEN (SELECT listagg(tugrou.description, chr(10)) 
                               within GROUP (ORDER BY tugmem.tuser_identifier,
                                                      tugrou.description)
                      FROM tugmem
                      JOIN tugrou ON tugrou.identifier = tugmem.tugrou_identifier
                      WHERE tugmem.tuser_identifier = tuser.identifier
                      GROUP BY tugmem.tuser_identifier) NOT LIKE '%AIS %' THEN 'SWIFT User ' 
                                || to_char((SELECT max(logon_date)
                                            FROM fife_logon_history
                                            WHERE user_name = tuser.name),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
              ELSE decode((SELECT max(logon_date)
                           FROM fife_logon_history
                           WHERE user_name = tuser.name),NULL, NULL, 'Last Login ' 
                                  || to_char((SELECT max(logon_date)
                                              FROM fife_logon_history
                                              WHERE user_name = tuser.name),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'))
          END "Application " ,
          nvl((SELECT to_char(max(logon_date), 'DD-MON-RRRR hh24:mi')
               FROM fife_logon_history
               WHERE user_name = tuser.name),'Never') "Last Logged In"
   FROM tuser
   JOIN person ON person.identifier = tuser.person_identifier
   JOIN bemplo ON bemplo.person_identifier = tuser.person_identifier
   JOIN ounit ON ounit.identifier = bemplo.ounit_identifier
   JOIN dba_users ON dba_users.username = tuser.name
   WHERE (((bemplo.employment_end_date IS NULL)
           AND (primary_employment = 'Y'))
          OR (BEMPLO.EMPLOYMENT_END_DATE =
                (SELECT MAX(EMPLOYMENT_END_DATE)
                 FROM BEMPLO B
                 WHERE B.PERSON_IDENTIFIER = TUSER.PERSON_IDENTIFIER))) )
WHERE ((("Last Logged In" != 'Never')
        AND ("Last Logged In" < to_char((sysdate -182), 'DD-MON-RRRR hh24:mi')))
       OR ("Last Logged In" = 'Never'))
  AND "Account Status" != 'LOCKED'
ORDER BY 1,
         4 ASC,
         5 ASC
```

This is the PLAN report

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                         |  6264 |    36M| 11944 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                     |                         |     1 |    15 |       |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | FIFE_LOGON_HISTORY      |     5 |    75 |     4 |
|   3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | FLHIST_USER             |     5 |       |     1 |
|   4 |  SORT AGGREGATE                     |                         |     1 |    15 |       |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | FIFE_LOGON_HISTORY      |     5 |    75 |     4 |
|   6 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | FLHIST_USER             |     5 |       |     1 |
|   7 |  SORT GROUP BY                      |                         |     1 |    40 |     3 |
|   8 |   NESTED LOOPS                      |                         |     2 |    80 |     3 |
|   9 |    VIEW                             | index$_join$_005        |   114 |  3534 |     3 |
|  10 |     HASH JOIN                       |                         |       |       |       |
|  11 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN           | TUGROU_PK               |   114 |  3534 |     1 |
|  12 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN           | TUGROU_TUGROU2_UK       |   114 |  3534 |     1 |
|  13 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | TUGMEM_TUGMEM2_UK       |     1 |     9 |     0 |
|  14 |  SORT GROUP BY                      |                         |     1 |    40 |     3 |
|  15 |   NESTED LOOPS                      |                         |     2 |    80 |     3 |
|  16 |    VIEW                             | index$_join$_008        |   114 |  3534 |     3 |
|  17 |     HASH JOIN                       |                         |       |       |       |
|  18 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN           | TUGROU_PK               |   114 |  3534 |     1 |
|  19 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN           | TUGROU_TUGROU2_UK       |   114 |  3534 |     1 |
|  20 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | TUGMEM_TUGMEM2_UK       |     1 |     9 |     0 |
|  21 |  SORT GROUP BY                      |                         |     1 |    40 |     3 |
|  22 |   NESTED LOOPS                      |                         |     2 |    80 |     3 |
|  23 |    VIEW                             | index$_join$_011        |   114 |  3534 |     3 |
|  24 |     HASH JOIN                       |                         |       |       |       |
|  25 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN           | TUGROU_PK               |   114 |  3534 |     1 |
|  26 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN           | TUGROU_TUGROU2_UK       |   114 |  3534 |     1 |
|  27 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | TUGMEM_TUGMEM2_UK       |     1 |     9 |     0 |
|  28 |  SORT AGGREGATE                     |                         |     1 |    15 |       |
|  29 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | FIFE_LOGON_HISTORY      |     5 |    75 |     4 |
|  30 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | FLHIST_USER             |     5 |       |     1 |
|  31 |  SORT AGGREGATE                     |                         |     1 |    15 |       |
|  32 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | FIFE_LOGON_HISTORY      |     5 |    75 |     4 |
|  33 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | FLHIST_USER             |     5 |       |     1 |
|  34 |  SORT AGGREGATE                     |                         |     1 |    15 |       |
|  35 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | FIFE_LOGON_HISTORY      |     5 |    75 |     4 |
|  36 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | FLHIST_USER             |     5 |       |     1 |
|  37 |  SORT AGGREGATE                     |                         |     1 |    15 |       |
|  38 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | FIFE_LOGON_HISTORY      |     5 |    75 |     4 |
|  39 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | FLHIST_USER             |     5 |       |     1 |
|  40 |  SORT ORDER BY                      |                         |  6264 |    36M| 11944 |
|  41 |   VIEW                              |                         |  6264 |    36M|  3973 |
|  42 |    CONCATENATION                    |                         |       |       |       |
|  43 |     FILTER                          |                         |       |       |       |
|  44 |      HASH JOIN                      |                         |  5389 |   999K|  2914 |
|  45 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL             | ORGANISATIONAL_UNITS    |  4046 |   106K|    21 |
|  46 |       HASH JOIN                     |                         |  5389 |   857K|  2892 |
|  47 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL            | BASE_EMPLOYEES          |  9996 |   175K|    33 |
|  48 |        HASH JOIN                    |                         |  2710 |   383K|  2858 |
|  49 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL           | TS$                     |    17 |    51 |     7 |
|  50 |         NESTED LOOPS                |                         |       |       |       |
|  51 |          NESTED LOOPS               |                         |  2710 |   375K|  2851 |
|  52 |           HASH JOIN                 |                         |  2745 |   324K|   104 |
|  53 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL        | TS$                     |    17 |    51 |     7 |
|  54 |            HASH JOIN                |                         |  2745 |   316K|    96 |
|  55 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL       | TAB_USERS               |  4778 |   121K|    14 |
|  56 |             HASH JOIN               |                         |  2868 |   257K|    81 |
|  57 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL      | USER_ASTATUS_MAP        |     8 |   152 |     2 |
|  58 |              HASH JOIN              |                         |  3227 |   230K|    79 |
|  59 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL     | PROFNAME$               |     3 |     9 |     2 |
|  60 |               HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER |                         |  3227 |   220K|    76 |
|  61 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL    | RESOURCE_GROUP_MAPPING$ |     1 |    29 |     2 |
|  62 |                HASH JOIN            |                         |  3227 |   129K|    74 |
|  63 |                 MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|                         |     2 |    36 |     4 |
|  64 |                  TABLE ACCESS FULL  | PROFILE$                |     1 |     9 |     2 |
|  65 |                  BUFFER SORT        |                         |     2 |    18 |     2 |
|  66 |                   TABLE ACCESS FULL | PROFILE$                |     2 |    18 |     2 |
|  67 |                 TABLE ACCESS FULL   | USER$                   |  4993 |   112K|    69 |
|  68 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PERSON_PK               |     1 |       |     0 |
|  69 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PERSONS                 |     1 |    21 |     1 |
|  70 |      SORT AGGREGATE                 |                         |     1 |    11 |       |
|  71 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | BASE_EMPLOYEES          |     2 |    22 |     3 |
|  72 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN             | BEMPLO_PERSON_FK_I      |     2 |       |     1 |
|  73 |     FILTER                          |                         |       |       |       |
|  74 |      HASH JOIN                      |                         |   875 |   162K|  1053 |
|  75 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL             | TS$                     |    17 |    51 |     7 |
|  76 |       HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER         |                         |   875 |   159K|  1046 |
|  77 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL            | RESOURCE_GROUP_MAPPING$ |     1 |    29 |     2 |
|  78 |        HASH JOIN                    |                         |   875 |   135K|  1043 |
|  79 |         NESTED LOOPS                |                         |       |       |       |
|  80 |          NESTED LOOPS               |                         |   875 |   111K|  1022 |
|  81 |           HASH JOIN                 |                         |   886 | 97460 |   135 |
|  82 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL        | BASE_EMPLOYEES          |   911 | 16398 |    33 |
|  83 |            HASH JOIN                |                         |  2745 |   246K|   101 |
|  84 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL       | TAB_USERS               |  4778 |   121K|    14 |
|  85 |             HASH JOIN               |                         |  2868 |   184K|    86 |
|  86 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL      | TS$                     |    17 |    51 |     7 |
|  87 |              HASH JOIN              |                         |  2868 |   176K|    79 |
|  88 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL     | USER_ASTATUS_MAP        |     8 |   152 |     2 |
|  89 |               HASH JOIN             |                         |  3227 |   138K|    76 |
|  90 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL    | PROFNAME$               |     3 |     9 |     2 |
|  91 |                HASH JOIN            |                         |  3227 |   129K|    74 |
|  92 |                 MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|                         |     2 |    36 |     4 |
|  93 |                  TABLE ACCESS FULL  | PROFILE$                |     1 |     9 |     2 |
|  94 |                  BUFFER SORT        |                         |     2 |    18 |     2 |
|  95 |                   TABLE ACCESS FULL | PROFILE$                |     2 |    18 |     2 |
|  96 |                 TABLE ACCESS FULL   | USER$                   |  4993 |   112K|    69 |
|  97 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PERSON_PK               |     1 |       |     0 |
|  98 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PERSONS                 |     1 |    21 |     1 |
|  99 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL           | ORGANISATIONAL_UNITS    |  4046 |   106K|    21 |
| 100 |      SORT AGGREGATE                 |                         |     1 |    11 |       |
| 101 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | BASE_EMPLOYEES          |     2 |    22 |     3 |
| 102 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN             | BEMPLO_PERSON_FK_I      |     2 |       |     1 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Note

- 'PLAN_TABLE' is old version

I am new to SQL (relearning) so any help would be apprecated

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In the question you mention several things and the conclusion is that the script behaves randomly. In order for us to help you can you provide a tiny, complete and reproducible example of the script which shows the current behaviour

Comment: Add tag which database you are using. It will be helpfull for all

Comment: Hi, like George mentioned you need to show some complete and reproducible case. It is impossible for anyone to read a query this size without knowing anything about your tables relationship, business rules and data itself to give you a help. Based on what you wrote and depending on where you are running your query there are a few things that you can look into.
So first "all the rows at once now its only doing it 50 at a time" this looks like a client configuration problem, the program you are using to run this query had its configuration changed somehow (maybe an update)...

Comment: Second "4500 users in the system and now its only returning between 1000 to 1500" this is most likely related with the data you have on your table and the filters you are applying on your query, since there are tons of DATE filters it is possible that today was the "turning" day... so you can start by removing those filters and test to see how the query behaves.
The best course of action for you is to divide and conquer, start by removing filters and testing the data that you get back and keep adding it until you find the culprit(s)

Comment: Hi so thanks for the reply, this is the first time I have looked for help outside my own support network. To give you some back ground. I inherited this 3 years ago it is a Case management Oracle and has 2500000 clients  database and have limited documentation and my DBA left to pastures new leaving some of the scripts like the one above. I have no Data schema or dictionary for the Oracle database and have had to rely on others to help me along, I have used this script with the Oracle SQL Developer for the last year and have had little issues with it.

Comment: It is used for returning the users that log and manage the system (over its life time) and their teams and other information. When I was using it last week it was fine and returning all users (with a few glitches due to cross referances in the system)

Comment: The PLAN statment show the script running through the correct numbers but it is not produccing the rows expected. I have asked my servers team if they have updated the SQL server to see if the issues is there

Comment: Look for configurations on your SQL Developer. It is a client and often these clients have configurations on the number of rows to return due limitations on memory usage. So for instance I work with MySQL and I use Workbench which by default limits any query to 1000 rows. I once changed that to return more and after an update it reverted my configuration. It may be the case for you. It is very unlikely that the issue is with the Server itself. So focus on your client and your query since it rely on DATE data.